# Action when item is deleted from Call Log?

Tags: android, calllog

Can i set a `cursor` or something like that to Call Log delete , because i need to synchronize to another database 
I solved when a call is finished then insert it but with delete i have no idea.

Anything could help thanks

Comment: `Context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(callloguri, true, yourcontentobserverimplementation)` you have to put this into some kind of pernamently running service ... (it will also recive notification on other operations like insert and update)

Comment: how can i get if from call log, was deleted something? can you send some code what i need to do in `onChange()` method

Comment: `if(uri.equals(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI)){

     final Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null, null, null);
     c.moveToFirst();
  while (c.moveToNext()){
   final int type = c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
   final int dircode = c.getInt(type);
   if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE==CustomPhoneStateListener.lastCallState&once==1&CallsMainFragment.firstcall){
    Toast.makeText(context, "No  Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    readCallLogs();
    once++;
    CallsMainFragment.firstcall=false;
   }
  }
 }`